# OpenCart 2.2: Instantly change the quantity if option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, opencart

I'm running an online store for contact lenses using OpenCart 2.2.

I would need to modify the product page a little in the following way :
 When you buy a contact lenses you have 2 dropdown lists where you select the diopter (power) for each eye. What I want to do is, if you select the power on for one eye only, the minimum quantity for purchase of the product to be 1, but if both eyes are selected, the minimum quantity should be 2.

So I'm thinking of a if-else-elseif function, because there are only 3 cases possible - 1 - Only left eye selected; 2 - Both eyes selected; 3 - Only right eye selected. [This is how the product page looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRqK.png).
Qty = 1 is by default, but I want to make it switch instantly to 2, if something is selected in both dropdown lists.

I suppose I would need some AJAX to do this? I have very minimum knowledge of AJAX.
I **DON'T** expect someone to do it for me, I'm just trying to find out what I would need to make it happen..

The real boner and what makes me lost is that the select options are named "option[XXX]" by default from OpenCart and the number ([xxx]) is different for each product on the store and each option..

Could anyone give me any clues if that is even possible?

**Edit :**
Here is how I display my select tags :

```
<div id="product">
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
             <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
             <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
                 <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                 <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                     <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                         (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                     <?php } ?>
                 </option>
                 <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <?php } ?>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Thanks for the answers! Here is the quantity HTML code as well:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
  <br />
  <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the part of the HTML displaying the two `select`s ?

Comment: Please show the HTML for the quantity field too

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use AJAX for this, it can be done just using jQuery/JavaScript:

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    var optionNames = ['power - right eye', 'power - left eye'];

    var $qtyInput = $('#product input[name=qty]');

    var $options = $('#product select').filter(function() {
      var text = $.trim($(this).prev('label').text().toLocaleLowerCase());

      return $.inArray(text, optionNames) > -1;
    });

    $options.on('change', function() {
      var selectedTotal = $options.filter(function() {
        return !!$(this).val();
      }).length;

      if (selectedTotal > 0) {
        $qtyInput.val(selectedTotal).prop('min', selectedTotal);
      }

    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="product">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="input-option1">power - left eye</label>
      <select name="option[1]" id="input-option1" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="input-option2">power - right eye</label>
      <select name="option[2]" id="input-option2" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" name="qty" value="1" min="1" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may need to change the selectors to match what you have because you didn't show us your quantity input field.

A couple other things to consider with this code:

The quantity is always set to 2 or 1, regardless of whether or not the user has already entered 6 for example. You may want to add in logic to stop this happening.

Also, OpenCart uses an `option_id` as well as a `product_option_id` for each option, with the `option_id` being the same ID regardless of what product you're on. It may be worth adding this to the select HTML so you can look up the elements more efficiently than checking the label's text value as I have done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have added the HTML code for the quantity.